# They are "masterpieces" or they are "a masterpiece"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it wrong if I say:

> Look at those reliefs, they are **a masterpiece**!

Because I consider each one of them individually and also because we also normally say:

> Taxes are **a** necessary evil.

Comment: We need more context to say. Are they individual pieces of art, to be appreciated separately, or are they several things to be considered as a single piece of art?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to answer fully without knowing what "they" are. But yes, if you are regarding them as a single creation, then  you can refer to them as a masterpiece.

This is irrespective of whether their creator(s) regarded them as a single item or not: you are free to regard them as such if you choose to. (Maybe you are making a bold and startling artistic statement by doing so!)

Comment: for example: Look at those reliefs, they are a masterpiece!

Comment: If the Mona Lisa was hanging on Angkor Wat and I observed them  and proclaimed, *Look at them they are **a** masterpiece,* that would sound odd and be difficult to understand.  If I made the same comment regarding the Terra Cota Soldiers, that would make perfect sense.  We are free to linguistically create amalgamated masterpieces but not all will be understood.